# Using start process to install awscli msi package on remote windows machine

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, packer

I am trying to use packer to provision awscli on a Windows machine. To install the awscli is use the following PowerShell script:

```
$download_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi'
$downloaddestination = 'C:\Program Files\awscli.msi'
$checkpath='C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI'
if (Test-Path $downloaddestination) {
  # // File exists do nothing
} else {
  # // File does not exist download it
  (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($download_url, $downloaddestination)
}
$env:SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS = 1
Start-Process $downloaddestination /qn -Wait | Out-Null
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
if (Test-Path $checkpath) {
  Write-Host "awscli installed"
} else {
  Write-Host "Installation failed"
}
```

I am unable to install awscli, its getting failed to install the MSI package even though its able to download the packege.

Comment: AFAICS the command should work, assuming that it's actually being run on a remote host (there's nothing in the code you posted that would do this). First troubleshooting measure would probably be to have the installer create a log (add the parameter `/l*v C:\awscli.log`).

Comment: the remote host is user specific should i need to mention the user id and pwd

Comment: You can obfuscate that information.

Comment: i am getting the follwoing error for the command i used Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\awscli.msi' /qn -Wait /l*v C:\awscli.log | out-null                A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/l*v'

Comment: It's `/l*v`, and you need to pass the argument list for the installer as an array (`/qn,/l*v,C:\awscli.log`) or as a string (`"/qn /l*v C:\awscli.log"`).

Comment: as part of logs found the following error code
`Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (88:E4) [03:26:02:150]: Product: AWS Command Line Interface     --     Access is denied.
  Access is denied.

Comment: the detailed log i have posted below take a look

Comment: Please DO NOT post information pertaining to your question as an answer. Use the edit link right below your question to include additional information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I use Python to install the cli, it makes updating easier too. I normally use cloud formation, cloud formation uses the userdata to invoke a script that is run by powershell.

The script looks like this:

```
mkdir c:\setup-downloads
cd \setup-downloads
curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3-amd64.exe --output python-inst.exe
.\python-inst.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
Start-Sleep -s 30
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Python37"
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts"
pip3 install awscli
```

Create a directory somewhere `mkdir c:\setup-downloads` . Change to that directory `cd \setup-downloads` I then use curl to download python: `curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3-amd64.exe --output python-inst.exe`

Then I run the install using **quiet** mode, and I set it up to install itself into the path, and installed for everyone `.\python-inst.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0`

I wait for this to *finish* `Start-Sleep -s 30` But you need to re*s*tart the powershell to actually access python so I run the following to set the environment variables:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Python37"
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts"
```

Now that I have python installed, and the environment variables configured I can install the cli as follows:

```
pip3 install awscli
```

If you run `aws --version` it works

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Jasons answer, calling the PowerShell file from an autoattend syncronusCommand block, however, I could not get pip3 command to be recognised.. setting the python env path inline I felt was a little *hacky*.

Check out - https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/ -  which explains that when using an MSI file the - *installation can be initiated programmatically.*

My PowerShell file now looks like this

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi -Outfile "C:\aws.msi"
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "c:\aws.msi", /qn
```

Now I have automated the install of aws cli on windows server.

Comment: This is the ticket.
No need for another language run-time, just run those two lines in your script!

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest changing the approach and installing aws cli via pip the [Python](https://www.python.org/) package manager that comes with the default Python installation.
Follow this [guide](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/) to install Python silently on windows. Then you can just run the command below and it will install the awscli.

```
pip install awscli
```

Comment: can you explain in detail, i think pip cannot be installed in windows, if yes please do explain full procedure

Answer (score -4):

You can use pip on windows, it's easy:
1.  download and Install Python 2.7 for Win x64 in Python27 folder (default) [I had trouble with Python3.0 but I may have installed it wrong]
       https://www.python.org/downloads/ 
2.  in control panel, system, advanced settings add (ie., "new") to the user or system variable:
        PYTHONPATH %PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27\Lib 
3.  in control panel, system, advanced settings, edit the system PATH variable and add at the end:  
          ;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\ 
4.  download the awscli package from 
        https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi 
5.  now you can run in the Windows DOS Command box:  "pip install --upgrade awscli" 
6.  you can run cli commands in Windows DOS Command box, powershell or powershell ise.  First run "aws configure" in powershell or win/dos command box 
7.  then you can run any CLI or CLI SDK command in powershell ise